# Why does my thread is freeze if I try to get the ObjectInputStream instead of InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, objectinputstream

It is about this line

```
VoIP_InputStream = new ObjectInputStream(VoIP_socket.getInputStream());
```

If I execute it in debug mode I see that the thread that is running it doesn't go on. It does just freeze at this line and exit the debugger without going on to the next line.

if I try this line instead (without ObjectInputStream)

```
VoIP_InputStream = VoIP_socket.getInputStream();
```

If runs normally through. Why does it freeze if I use the ObjectInputStream and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because, as it says in the Javadoc, the constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads the stream header written by the constructor of `ObjectOutputStream` at the peer. You need to construct the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends preferably.